# Opencart, OC 1.5.1.3, captcha error

Tags: apache, captcha, opencart

OC 1.5.1.3, the Captcha image doesn't show on none of these pages:

1. product / review section
2. contact page
3. by accessing this http://www.directmall.co.uk/index.php?route=information/contact/captcha (the direct link which should generate the image)

I can't see any errors (Apache logs / error.txt file). I can't see any spaces within the language files - in fact I've redownloaded the entire EN package just to make sure..

I suspect a broken dependency (even if I have GD.. there must be something else..); disabled entirely caching - need assistance!

Back in 2009 I've found trails of such errors on forums but it seems there was a language-file problem, meaning trails of spaces were sending the page headers earlier than normal - but I've checked most of the files I thought to be involved and I've cleaned all the extra spaces - with no result.

Thanks,
Bogdan

Answer (score 14):

FYI I had this same problem and this solution (change to system\library\captcha.php) *did* make the captcha image display successfully and the form passes validation:

```
function getCode(){
$out = ob_get_contents();
$out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "", $this->code);
ob_end_clean();

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you thank you thank you. No one in OC forum knows the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For OC 1.5.* Go to

> system\library\captcha.php

Find `function getCode()` Replace this function to

```
function getCode(){
$code= ob_get_contents();
$code= str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "", $this->code);
ob_end_clean()    return $code; }
```

Now For OC 2.1.* Go to

> Catalog/controller/captcha/basic-captcha

Find `$this->session->data['captcha'] = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 17, 6);`

place below code after this

```
    $code= ob_get_contents();
    $code= str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "",$this->session->data['captcha']);
    ob_end_clean();
    $this->session->data['captcha'] = $code;
```

And For OC 2.3.* Go to

> Catalog/controller/Extension/captcha/basic-captcha.php
>   Find `$this->session->data['captcha'] = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 17, 6);`
>   Place below code after this

```
    $code= ob_get_contents();
    $code= str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "",$this->session->data['captcha']);
    ob_end_clean();
    $this->session->data['captcha'] = $code;
```

Its helpfull !

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `view-source:http://www.directmall.co.uk/index.php?route=information/contact/captcha` on Google Chrome  showed me that there's a whitespace at the front of the content of the image.

You might have accidentally outputted `"\n"` somewhere in your code before `<?php` or after `?>`,

Comment: Tried: /system/library/captcha.php, /index.php, /catalog/language/english/english.php - I understand what you're saying, this problem was discussed within many web forums back in 2008/2009 but now I can't think of where the space is fitted. The http://www.directmall.co.uk/index.php?route=information/contact/captcha path involves less includes than all the other ones but I still can't see the problem within the files mentioned above. There might be a charset issue - I have UTF-8 set for the ones above. I appreciate very much your assistance, please advice.

Comment: You should check your php error log (if it's enabled) - this isn't the same as the opencart error log. That should have the error message in there for headers already sent, along with where the output was started (a line number and a file)

Comment: No errors - I know it's unlikely but I can't see any errors and I run E_ALL. Plesk 10 upgraded from Plesk 9.

Answer (score 1):

you should add this code after your getcode function (captcha.php in the library)

```
$out = ob_get_contents();
$out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "", $input);
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Still no result..... I've literally added these 2 lines between "function getCode(){" and "return $this->code;". I've changed the return from "$this->code;" to "$out" too and I've changed "$input" with "$this->code" and still no result in all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify for anyone looking for this.
system/library/captcha.php

change function line 11 getCode()

to this:

```
function getCode(){
    //return $this->code;
    $out = ob_get_contents();
            $out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "", $input);
            ob_end_clean();

            return $out;
}
```

This ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i my particular case, this was the solution. Probably when fixing product.php some blank lines were introduced, which are extremely difficult to debug. In any case this code :

```
$out = ob_get_contents();
$out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "", $input);
ob_end_clean();

return $out;
```

did fix it, since it cleans anything that should not be there.

hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue recently and this common solution (that worked for me before) didn't work:

```
$out = ob_get_contents();
$out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "", $input);
ob_end_clean();
return $out;
```

I noticed that the showImage() method in /system/library/captcha.php accesses $this->code directly rather than using its getter, getCode(). That means it's bypassing the function to strip whitespace.

However, modifying the constructor like this did the trick:

```
function __construct() { 
    $this->code = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 17, 6); 
    $this->code = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "", $this->code);
}
```

More info and a vQmod extension to apply this fix can be found here: 
http://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/opencart-captcha-not-working-jfif/