# opencart contact page captcha is not comming

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart, captcha

I am facing a problem that my captcha is not coming on contact page. Please have a look.

http://www.lewevaaboutique.com/store/index.php?route=information/contact

then i set it up  on my local host and did the modification  according to this thread

[Opencart, OC 1.5.1.3, captcha error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263452/opencart-oc-1-5-1-3-captcha-error)  and it started working on my local

Then i did the same thing on to the server but  captcha  problem is still there

Please help me in this issue

Comment: when i go to your site and inspect it with firebug it says it cant load...index.php?route=information/contact/captcha.... maybe you need to change that to /store/index.php?route=information/contact/captcha ???? and i get big fat warnings on top of you page about sessions and cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Headers already sent" means that your PHP script already sent the HTTP headers, and as such it can't make modifications to them now.

Check two things

1) Check that you don't send ANY content before calling session_start. 
2) `<?php` is the first character not even tab or space

Comment: thank you  that was the problem of the header .Can you help me in one thing i just resolved the hedder problem at server captcha start comming but on local i have to do this as well why?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263452/opencart-oc-1-5-1-3-captcha-error

Comment: Sorry bro i am not an php expert but had used it some years back and now work on java based web applications. I was able to help you cause i saw your error and this basic error is same across any language.